# How to lock touchscreen without turning it off?

Tags: lock-screens

Pressing power button both turns off the screen (even if some application holding wakelock) and stops receiving input from it.

How to stop receiving input (and require password to get into normal mode again), but still show what is the foreground application displaying, like "view only" mode.

Example scenario:

1. I open compass application;
2. I use that "lock, but not hide" thing;
3. Now touching the screen just does nothing, but the application is still updating things on it;
4. I press power button (unlock);
5. It asks to slide for unlock and/or password;
6. Unlocked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an application which does it pretty well.

Check out at https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.argotronic.touchblocker

Answer (score 1):

I have same issue with my s5, the screen flickers and once it dims it's hard to turn back on. So i downloaded keep screen on app so it doesn't turn off, then i downloaded touch lock app to prevent apps from being pressed when it's in my pocket.